# How to set Mongo Service URI as variable with username and password in Gitlab CI?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using **Gitlab CI** with **Nodejs** and **MongoDB**. I am having trouble with establishing a connection with Mongo service in CI. I am passing Mongo URI as an env variable. Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```
image: node:8.12.0

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

services:
  - mongo
  - redis

variables:
  MONGO_URI: 'mongodb://mongo:27017/testDB?authMechanism=DEFAULT'

connect:
  image: redis
  script:
    - redis-cli -h redis PING

tests:
  script:
    - yarn && yarn test:integration
```

I have also tried using Mongo URI with username and password, with both being `admin`, like below:

`MONGO_URI: 'mongodb://admin:admin@mongo:27017/testDB?authMechanism=DEFAULT'`

In both cases, this is the error I am getting:

```
MongooseTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
```

Inside my code, `mongoose.createConnection()` is causing the above error.

The same CI was working before,  but after upgrading my packages `mongo` refused to connect to a URI without username and password. In my local machine, I create a new user in mongo with a username and password, then it worked fine as earlier. But I am clueless how to pass **Mongo URI with username and password** for Gitlab CI mongo service or does there exist any default username and password to pass the URL?

Any leads would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The username and password can be written directly in the [connection string]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html#connection-string-uri-format), but I don't know if gitlab-ci will recognize that.

Comment: @Joe I had tried that also previously! Still, it was having the same issue.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Facing similar issue and looking for any leads.

Comment: Not yet! The only lead I had was this happened when I updated the libraries I was using. Reverted back to old versions once I start getting this error. Still no help.